# Excel VBA: can delete validation but not add new one

Tags: excel, validation, vba

My code is as follows

```
If Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "" And (Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "" Or Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "") Then
    Sheets("MySheet").Activate
    Cells(Target.Row, 3).Activate
    ActiveCell.Validation.Delete
    If (Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "Type A") Then
        ActiveCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=AvailableVersions"
    ElseIf (Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "Type B") Then
        ActiveCell.Validation.Delete
    Else
        ActiveCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="9999999"
    End If
End If
```

So the issue I am having comes whenever I reach ActiveCell.Validation.Add

```
Run Time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Not a very helpful error, and also this occurs with both number and list validation type, so I am sure it is not an issue with the list itself which has workbook level scope anyway.  It never occurs on ActiveCell.Validation.Delete which I find weird?

I have been all over google trying to find a solution, and most suggest that it is caused by running dynamic validation code from a button which hogs focus despite the Activate call, but I am running on sheet change event rather than on button press so I don't think this is my issue - any ideas?  I've wasted basically a whole day on this! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would be fine, if you weren't running it from a worksheet event. For me the issue occurs when you try to select a new cell from within the event procedure. I rewrote what it looked like your code was trying to do without selecting a different cell.

Try this:

```
If Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "" And (Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "" Or Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "") Then
    With Sheets("MySheet")
        .Cells(Target.Row, 3).Validation.Delete
        If (.Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "Type A") Then
            .Cells(Target.Row, 3).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=AvailableVersions"
        ElseIf (.Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "Type B") Then
            .Cells(Target.Row, 3).Validation.Delete
        Else
            .Cells(Target.Row, 3).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="9999999"
        End If
    End With
End If
```

The other possible error would be if `AvailableVersions` is not a valid defined name for a list.

Comment: I consider it best practice to avoid ActiveSheet, ActiveCell, Selection, etc... as much as possible.  The above does this using `With`, and also, of course, you can also assign to variables.  Sometimes one needs to capture Active.. or Selection, in those cases, capture it (to a variable) and then don't rely on them anymore. Sadly, the macro recorder generally give you code following what I might consider worst practice, that is, to depend on Selection/Select, and ActiveXXX/Activate every other line or so.

Comment: @ErikEidt Indeed, I was tempted to assign `.Cells(Target.Row, 3).Validation` simply to make the code smaller... obviously I didn't though.

Comment: sure either way;  I'm just trying to provide some additional methodological motivation as to why your answer is a good one, above and beyond what you'd directly stated regarding being within an event handler.